# In which file 404 page redirection happening in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

i want to know from where the 404 page redirection happened?.Because i need to redirect to custom.php instead 404 page.

is this possible?..if it is where do i change the code?.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to substitute the error page (which in wordpress is called 404.php) by your own. Just go to the folder where your theme is stored, and you will find there the 404.php (if it doesn't exist, no problem). Rename your **custom.php** to **404.php** and put it in your theme's folder, and you should have it.

You can read more information in [this article at wodpress.org about creating an Error 404 Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Comment: i have 404.php in my theme folder.but i want to know how the redirection happens..i want to know the exact redirection coding file.

Comment: I believe that when an error occurs, it's the main index.php file in a wordpress install the one that gets the error, like (in the case of a 404 error) /index.php?error=404. Of course, you could change this in your .htaccess file by adding this line: ErrorDocument 404 /custom.php